# Exponential growth percentage conversion

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, percentages

The question states:

> If bacteria is doubling in size every 20 minutes, at what % rate is
> the number of bacteria increasing every hour?

So firstly using the rule of 70, I approximated that the percentage growth rate is 3.5%. This is however every minute. How do I convert it to every hour, should I just multiply it by 60? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If bacteria is doubling in size every 20 minutes, what about the size after 40 minutes?, and after 60 minutes?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well in 60 minutes it's a factor of 8 right? So then 8 = (1+r) so r = 7, thus p = 700%. Is there a way tho how to convert it from minutes (3.5%) to hours (700%) such that I am able to use the rule of 70 in the beginning?

Comment: Yes, after one hour the size increases by a factor of 8. That is the exact solution (equivalent to a 700 % growth).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rule of 70, if I understand correctly, it is used to obtain a rough estimate of the doubling time, given a growth rate. However, in this case, you can compute the exact solution.

Comment: After a quick google, I'm guessing the rule of 70 should apply to low % growth rates. $time to double = \frac{70}{growth rate}$
Example 1: with an hourly rate of 70 %, the rule of 70 gives you a doubling time of 1 hour, which is not accurate.

Comment: Example 2: If you input $1/3$ hours as "time to double", the rule of 70 gives you an hourly growth rate of $210 \%$ which is far away from the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, after every $20$ minutes, the bacteria would double in size. This would mean that since $60=20\times3$, so the size of the bacteria after the $60$ minutes would be $2^3=8$ times the size of the bacteria before the $60$ minutes. But the question asks for the percentage, so it should probably be $800-100=700\%$, because it asks for the growth, and not the entire comparison (if you know what I mean).